# Why are satellite phones strictly banned in India?

Tags: legal, india, cellphones

Is it true, that using or travelling with satellite phone is strictly and unconditionally banned in India? And if yes, is there any explanation or official reason, why?

I have found such information, when browsing various sources before my business trip to India, though I can't recall that particular source, so I wish to confirm this, quite surprising, information.

I can understand banning usage of such devices in areas, places or installation related to national security, police, army etc. But country-wide, unconditional ban for these devices, with underlined addition, that confiscation, high money fine or even up to three years in jail sentence may be executed, even after declaring such device on entry -- that is something beyond my imagination.

Comment: "Because terrorism" is the answer to most security-related questions. The terrorists have sadly won a long time ago.

Comment: Not a good situation for mountaineers, I guess. There's some stuff about INMARSAT being allowed, with specific permission.

Comment: "confiscation, high money fine or even up to three years in jail sentence may be executed, even after declaring such device on entry -- that is something beyond my imagination." Declaring them on entry would probably mean lesser punishment. But declaration shouldn't be expected to be a free pass: suppose you showed up at customs and said, "Hi! I've got these illegal narcotics and these illegal weapons." I'm pretty sure the response wouldn't be "Oh, OK. Give them to us and you're free to enjoy the rest of your trip!" Why would illegal [something else] be any different?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on legal.se, not travel.se.

Comment: SAT phones can't be tapped by the government. Everything else is just justification.

Comment: @Calchas Assuming that: (a) information on banned satellite phones were found by my on a _travel_ site (Wikitravel), (b) information on what you can or can't bring with you, when _travelling_ is IMHO strictly bind to travelling... let me say, that I disagree with you. Do you also think, that asking about, what you should buy when _travelling_ somewhere belongs to a shopping discussion forum? Stack Exchange sites are mostly blend of topics, ya know...

Comment: There is an employee of the month poster on right now at Cochin International Airport, said employee chosen for detection and confiscation of satellite phone (thuraya)... UAE national ( also written that he was handed over to local police). Found this post while searching for why it's banned.

Comment: It's simply because of the "terrorism scare".  It would be like asking "why are there strict bag checks in US airports?!"

Comment: @Fattie I don't relate (directly) terrorism to satellite phones usage. On contrary, I do relate bag checks to anti-terrorism policy. You have bag checks actually in every country, on every airport, all around the world and you have satellite phone usage ban in India only and maybe in a few more countries. So your compare isn't that strict, simple and obvious.

Comment: actually I'm not sure if you realize @trejder - simply **getting a cellphone** (I mean for tourists/visitors) is completely impossible in India. they are incredibly strict about it. You know how in most countries, it is trivial to say rent a cellphone (if you are a tourist) or just quickly get a cellphone account.  In India getting a cellphone is more like getting say a driver's license - you identity is thoroughly checked etc.

Comment: you're aware that sat phones are banned (or highly regulated) in a number of countries?  Just google.  Indeed, they are banned in China (the most populous country) and highly regulated in Russia (the largest country).

Comment: [P&O also ban satellite phones on their ships](https://ask.pocruises.com/help/PO/before-you-sail/not_allowed)

Comment: This is one of those questions that, if it were about the US, would immediately be moved to a more relevant stackexchange. But because it’s about India and most of the Western world that is online just considers that a travel destination it is asked here and left alone.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The use of satellite phones violates the [Indian Telegraph Act, 1885](http://www.ijlt.in/pdffiles/Indian-Telegraph-Act-1885.pdf), the [The Indian Wireless Telegraph Act, 1933](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/in/in037en.pdf), the [Indian Penal Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Penal_Code), and the [Foreigners Order of 1948](https://web.archive.org/web/20170110203610/http://artassam.nic.in/Passport%20Deptt/Foreigners%20Orders%201948%20Order%20Under%20The%20ForeignersAct,%201946.pdf). The [Government of India declared satellite phones as threat to national security](http://www.dnaindia.com/india/report-satellite-phones-in-declared-as-threat-to-national-security-1590901) because of several recent act of terrorism.

Use of satellite phones for personal and commercial use is prohibited in the country. Only security agencies and defense forces can use it legally. To use any sort of satellite phone, permission has to be taken from the Department of Telecommunications (DoT). Please check out [this article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indian_Telegraph_Act,_1885#Satellite_Phones) on Wikipedia as well.

Comment: I'm curious how an 1885 law banned an item that wasn't invented until a hundred years later... maybe you could specify exactly where in the Indian Telegraph Act the key clauses are?

Comment: @TylerH The only reasonable explanation to me is that Indian telecoms law operates under a baseline what's not explicitly permitted is illegal basis; and for obvious reasons none of the pre-space age laws allowed satphones.

Comment: @TylerH "Within India, the Central Government shall have
exclusive privilege of establishing, maintaining and working telegraphs" and "'telegraph’ means any appliance [...] used [...] for transmission or reception of signs, signals, writing, images and sounds or intelligence of any nature by wire, visual or other electro-magnetic emissions, radio waves or Hertzian waves, galvanic, electric or magnetic means." That's how.

Comment: @MrLemon So I guess there's no amateur HAM radio market in India...

Comment: No WiFi in India either? NFC (i.e. every modern cell phone) forbidden? Heck, even my VISA card which contains a transponder chip, is illegal? As is my passport?

Comment: @Damon you are taking it too far. Just because they forbid to bring dogs, doesn't mean they will take issue with your parrot. What MrLemon stated is that the telegraph act gives the Gov. regulatory powers over telecommunications. How they enforce said powers on different technologies is a case by case. So no jumping to conclusions. Also, transponder and NFC chips are reactive (not active) devices.

Comment: @TylerH The bottom line here is that India is a huge country and terrorism poses a significant threat to the nation. In recent times India saw many terrorism and insurgency activities. Jammu & Kashmir, and Northeastern regions are particularly know for that. Satellite phones can be used for untraceable communication, and so it is obvious that the government wants to regulate such devices. Even to get a cellular phone connection in India, unlike many western nations, you need to provide an identity proof, an address proof and an existing local connection holder who can verify your identity.

Comment: One side note: In Jammu & Kashmir region, any prepaid cellular connection bought from anywhere else in India does not work. (Roaming is not supported in J&K telecom circle for pre-pay numbers of other telecom circles.) This step was also taken by government for security reason.

Comment: @TylerH the 1885 law has been amended; that's how it can mention technologies that did not exist in 1885.

Comment: @boroxun Sure, I wasn't criticizing India for their law, just musing about its implications.

Comment: @phoog That wouldn't be an 1885 law, then. It'd be a whatever-year-it-was-amended-in law.

Comment: @TylerH I am not able to change the Indian legal community's approach to identifying Indian legislation.

Comment: @phoog True, but you can change how you structure responses to queries about it :-) (e.g. "there was a 1991 amendment to the original 1885 act")

Comment: @MrLemon Forget NFC... with that definition, cards with mag strips are illegal.

Comment: @Mindwin Are you sure the NFC radio in a phone is non-active? That sounds wrong. An RFID tag is not itself active, but it generally must react to something which is active (like the NFC radio in a phone.)

Comment: @reirab The main point in my comment is that people were taking the ban on ONE tech (sat phone) and "crying wolf" that everything radio-related was also banned. But I specifically said "**chips**" - not radios.

Comment: @Mindwin I think those people were responding to MrLemon's comment which quoted the actual law. It's extremely vague and really does include most or all of what people were talking about. Even a magnetic card strip would be included in the definitions in that law. Also, the NFC chip in a phone contains the radio I was referring to.

Comment: @reirab The law puts telecommunications of any kind under the control of the government, as similar laws on every civlized country (and most of the rest also). MrLemon quoted the abrangence of the law, they jumped into (wrong) conclusions that other technologies were also banned. These comments were potentially harmful, as someone could take them as truthy, given the amount of traffic and search hits Stack sites gather. That is why I said they were "crying wolf". I concede on the confusion between NFC chips, NFC tags and NFC receiver/transmitter.

Comment: @Mindwin All countries regulate e-m emissions and communications, but not all countries give their central government "exclusive privilege of establishing, maintaining and working telegraphs" where 'telegraphs' is defined to mean any sort of communication mechanism. If you happen to have more knowledge of the other laws and/or jurisprudence surrounding this law and why it would ban sat phones, but not every other sort of communication mechanism that isn't "established, maintained, and worked" by the government, that would make a good answer.

Comment: Just stupidity mate. I wouldn't worry too much about it. Their army didnt worry either when it gave one of their sat phones to a news reporter, IN A WAR. How stupid can the military of a country get ? https://kalyan97.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/gen-malik-please-tell-the-nation-what-barkha-did-at-kargil-jay-bhattacharjee/

Answer (score 3):

Amateur (ham) radio is certainly legal in India and takes place regularly. 
Not being from India, I can only offer an electronics expert's possible explanation.

The vast majority of voice ham radio - VHF, UHF and the HF spectrum - operate by either a 'line of sight' or 'skip' propagation method. Additionally, it's fairly uncommon for ham radio operators to communicate with someone directly overhead - they nearly always are contacting and conversing with someone located at some distance on the horizon from them.  These communications leave a clear path which is subject to easy intercept (monitoring).

While hams do use satellite communications, there are relatively few ham satellites and the communications going through them is easily monitored.  While satellite phones also use the same radio waves, their communication is intended (and always takes place) with a repeater *above* the horizon.

What's the meaning of all that?  In a nutshell, it's possible for a sat phone to be down in a wide hole (or deep valley), communicating through a satellite passing directly overhead. The 'line of sight' in these cases would not extend to the horizon to any degree.  Therefore, these conversations are extremely difficult to monitor, with the notable exception being electronic intelligence (ELINT) aircraft flying overhead or intelligence satellites.

I'm not aware of India having an intelligence satellite or the necessary infrastructure to easily decrypt and intercept the satellite phones' conversations.  Know that I'm not implying that India doesn't have the technical knowhow, but I believe that they have much bigger fish to fry and eliminating the legal use of satellite phones is probably an easier method of keeping comms where they can be intercepted and intelligence gleaned from them acted upon.

That's my 2 cents and I'm certainly subject to being wrong about the above conclusions.

Comment: @TylerH  Who knows *how* they label laws in India?  In the United States, we still operate under the Communications Act of 1934 - "as amended by the Telecommunications Act of 1996" and that last phrase frequently isn't quoted.  :)

Comment: While what you say seems plausible, whether or not it's the answer to the question is pure speculation. Given that Indian laws appear to be that telecommunications devices are only allowed if explicitly permitted, it's also possible that the only reason satellite phones aren't allowed is that it was never felt important enough to pass a law authorizing their use. Having said that, one suspects that the answer to any question of the form "Why did government X do or not do Y?" is likely to be purely speculative.

Comment: This from another site:  "The use of satellite phones violates Section 4 of the Indian telegraph act of 1885,  the Indian Wireless Telegraph Act of 1933 and the Indian Penal Code and the Foreigners Order of 1948.  The government of India has stated that they are not able to intercept ingoing and outgoing calls on satellite phones, therefore because of the ongoing threat of terrorism, the technology is forbidden.  Anyone wishing to bring a sat phone into India, needs to first get a licence which will then need to be presented to the police and immigration."

Comment: Ham radio is generally required to be unencrypted. Not sure if that's still the case in India. But if it's not encrypted, they can intercept it.

Comment: Ham radio is legal in India. But, you need to write an exam (in Morse code) and get a license. My friend had license that he carried around with him at all times. Simply, to transmit anything, you need a license (with some exceptions). Receiving is legal, without any licence.