# Can I use a personal satellite phone/Internet connection as a passenger in a plane?

Tags: air-travel, cellphones, electronic-items, internet

I am reading some contradictory statements regarding the use of a personal satellite phone/Internet connection in a plane. E.g.:

https://www.bluecosmo.com/satellite-phones

> Hardened structures, buildings, mountains, and heavy tree cover can all negatively affect your signal. Pilots often leave a satellite phone or an Iridium GO! on the dashboard of their plane’s cockpit to receive a signal.

https://www.outfittersatellite.com/5-Common-Myths-about-Satellite-Phones_b_19.html:

> You can absolutely use a satellite phone indoors, whether in a building, car, boat, **airplane, or any other enclosed space as long as you install an unobstructed antenna on the outside of the vehicle** or structure. Outfitter Satellite carries kits for [in-building](https://www.outfittersatellite.com/fixed.html), [in-vehicle](https://www.outfittersatellite.com/vehicle.html), [in-aircraft](https://www.outfittersatellite.com/aero.html), and [marine satellite phones](https://www.outfittersatellite.com/marine.html). The idea of always needing to step outside or lean dangerously out a car window to use your satellite phone is incorrect.

The first statement claims that the device might be used within the plane whereas the second one mention it is required to have an antenna outside the plane, which confuses me.

Can I use a personal satellite phone/Internet connection as a passenger in a plane? By "can", I mean both legally and technically (= will it have a usable connection, assuming that I cannot plant an [antenna](https://www.satphonestore.com/iridium-aviation-antenna.html) on the outside of the plane prior to the flight).

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122443/discussion-on-question-by-franck-dernoncourt-can-i-use-a-personal-satellite-phon).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

### Technical Aspects

The key part of the quote about pilots leaving the sat phone on the dash is the 'dash' part. The dash is under a glass surface, which is almost completely transparent to RF signals and has a nice, wide view of the sky, where the satellites are. This will not translate well to the cabin, where the fuselage is not made of glass and is decidedly not transparent to RF signals. And where the only windows are relatively narrow and point sideways, not up. On older aircraft models, the fuselage is made of aluminum, which is quite conductive and, thus, will block your signal. While newer models of aircraft fuselages are often made of lighter carbon composite materials instead, it turns out that [they still have to surround it with a conductive mesh for lightning safety](https://www.flightglobal.com/boeing-confident-787-lightning-protection-will-pass-faa-scrutiny/81893.article), so those probably won't work well, either. Basically, the fuselage acts as a big [Faraday cage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faraday_cage).

This is why all of the antennas for aircraft systems, including the in-flight Wi-Fi, are located on the outside of the fuselage, typically inside some type of aerodynamic, but RF-transparent fairing mounted to either the bottom or top of the fuselage depending on the sort of network it needs to connect to. Antennas for terrestrial networks will generally be located on the bottom and antennas for satellite networks will generally be located on the top because airlines usually like to operate their aircraft in such a manner that the ground is more-or-less down, while the sky is more-or-less up.

If you're sitting at a window seat and can hold the sat phone's antenna up to the window, then it's possible that you could get a reasonable connection. I've done that with GPS receivers in a cell phone, for example, and could get a usable signal, even despite how weak the GPS signals are. However, if you're in the middle section of a widebody, you can probably forget about it.

### Legal Aspects

The legal question can vary dramatically depending on where you are and each jurisdiction often has quirky rules that often don't make a lot of intuitive sense.

For example, [in India, the personal or commercial use of a satellite phone is illegal](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/64974/12011), regardless of whether or not you're on an airplane.

Another quirky example is the United States. [The use of cellular radio signals is banned while in flight in the United States.](https://www.law.cornell.edu/cfr/text/47/22.925) Another odd quirk is that this rule technically applies even to the crew, not just passengers, and even on private aircraft. Oh, and the FCC itself has said that the rule is outdated since at least 2004, but it's still on the books and still enforced with regard to airline passengers (though generally ignored for private pilots.) However, that ban applies solely to cellular radios and so sat phones are perfectly legal.

However, using a sat phone (or anything) to actually make a voice call is another matter. Some airlines ([such as Delta](https://ir.delta.com/news/news-details/2013/Delta-CEO-Affirms-No-Voice-Calls-During-Flight-for-Customers/default.aspx)) explicitly ban making any sort of voice call during flight simply because most passengers don't want to be disturbed by others making calls during flight and flight attendants don't want to deal with the ensuing conflicts and disruptions. And, yet other airlines ([such as United](https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/inflight/devices.html)) ban any sort of radio transmitter, except for the specifically approved ones, such as Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.

Until relatively recently, there were several Asian countries (including China and South Korea) that banned the use of any sort of wireless transmission for the duration of flight (including even Wi-Fi and Bluetooth.) I think most of these have been repealed over the last several years, but I wouldn't be surprised if there are some still hanging on out there.

In short, the only general answer for knowing whether you would be allowed to use a sat phone for a given flight would be to check directly with the carrier you intend to fly. And, for international flights, ask specifically about the route you're interested in if the airline doesn't have a general ban on them for all of their flights. And remember that an airline's rules with regard to in-flight conduct typically carry some degree of force of law almost everywhere in the world, so intentionally violating them isn't a good idea. Similarly, even if the airline's rules don't specifically ban something, if a crew member tells you to stop, then stop.

Comment: `airlines usually like to operate their aircraft in such a manner that the ground is more-or-less down, while the sky is more-or-less up.` as a passanger I very much agree with the airlines here.

Comment: From a practical standpoint the view from a plane window to a LEO satellite constellation is very limited.  These satellites move past every few minutes and require quite a wide angle view of the sky to maintain line of sight to the satellites so that the connection can switch from one satellite to the next.. I have had problems maintaining an Iridium connection with an antenna mounted on the outside wall of a building with a view of almost half of the sky.

Comment: @YanickSalzmann [But Maverick doesn't](https://youtu.be/wUZxSf_P2r0?t=41).

Comment: @reirab well he does live in the [Danger zone](https://youtu.be/kUsFWO08CO0)

Comment: “sat phones are perfectly legal”—not according to the documentation that came with my Iridium device.

Comment: @WGroleau it's difficult to keep printed documentation up to date with changing laws. (Note that I have no idea how old _your_ phone is, nor if you're looking at printed or on-line docs.)'

Comment: @WGroleau Is it possibly from before the PED rules were repealed back around 2013? Many (most?) airliners have satellite phones built-in these days, so they're definitely not illegal to operate while airborne like cell phones are. Of course, carriers are within their rights to make rules against passengers using them, as noted in the answer with regard to United and, for voice calls, Delta. Aside from the carrier-specific rules, I'm not aware of any general rules against sat phone use in planes in the U.S., though. Does your documentation elaborate on which rules are of concern?

Comment: No, just claims that it "MUST be turned off" while on a plane.

Comment: The US ban on cell phones was originally due to an airplane being able to see hundreds of cell-phone antennas at once.  Older cell phones would try to maintain contact with every antenna they could reach for better handovers between cells, and an airliner full of cell phones could easily overload an entire city's network.  That's no longer an issue, but the ban's retained because an airliner full of people yacking away on their phones risks driving people insane.

Comment: @Mark Yep, that's exactly it. Unfortunately, they retained the present outdated FCC rule instead of replacing it with a DoT rule that addresses the current actual issue, though, which means that it remains technically illegal even for general aviation where passengers yacking away isn't a problem.

Comment: @WGroleau Ah, that's probably left over documentation from the pre-2013 PED rules, then, when that was indeed a legal (though oft-ignored) requirement. Nowadays, they actually sell them specifically for use on planes (mostly for use by pilots.)

Comment: Could be.  Bought it in 2014.

Comment: @Mark Yeah, they used to tell people that it was because phones could interfere with the communications and operations of the aircraft, which I never bought, because if there was *any* chance of that, you simply wouldn't be allowed to bring phones on planes at all unless it was verified turned off and in checked baggage.  If it was actually anywhere close to that dangerous, they wouldn't just trust that everyone would keep them turned off for the whole flight.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman That was a different rule. That was the PED rule that was repealed in 2013. It applied to all electronic devices, not just cell phones, but was only for when under 10,000 feet. It was specifically due to potential interference with the ILS [which is indeed a real problem](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/11555/755). In cases of landing in very low visibility, pilots may still request that electronics be turned off for this reason. The cell phone rule has always been about (now-outdated) interference with the cell network. It's an FCC rule, not an FAA rule.

Answer (score 7):

Others have addressed the question from the point of view of whether you can (technically), and whether you can (legally), use your satellite phone during your flight.  However there is one other aspect you should consider, and that is whether you *should* use your satellite phone during your flight.

I, and I think many others, see such travel time as an opportunity to be quiet and welcome being temporarily uncontactable.  You don't state the purposes in which you would need to use your satellite phone, but even if you can, you should first ask yourself (for example): "will I be disturbing my fellow passengers?", "is this call really that urgent that it cannot wait until we are back on the ground?", or "am I really going to get fired for being uncontactable for a couple of hours?"

Of course, there may be emergency situations, like: you are the president and war has broken out, or your partner's baby has arrived and you need to rebook your return to go back home as quickly as possible, but not much else comes to mind.

Comment: I expect most presidents can use a satellite phone on flights, and babies don't usually come as a complete surprise so the second example is bad planning.

Comment: @gerrit, babies do sometimes come early, up to 3 months early is not that uncommon and many of those babies survive their early entry, more than 3 months is mostly more of an emergency. I think it is a valid point.

Comment: Wait, you expect _me_ to think of _others_? What kind of world do you think we live in? Oh, a polite one where people think of others and not just of their own selfish needs, what a novel concept.

Answer (score 6):

Both your quotes only address the technical aspect of it, and make it clear you need to be in a position where the signal from the satellites is not obstructed by the structure of the plane, which is nearly impossible in most planes.

A window seat is unlikely to make much of a difference. On most planes, windows are small, often very badly placed (quite low), and offer a very limited view of the sky. Considering that the satellites involved move quite quickly, the limited field of view makes it very difficult to have a satellite in sight (and actually pointing towards you) quite. Also it would be interesting to check the bands used by the various sat phone systems, it’s quite possible the wavelength actually exceeds the size of the windows!

It is possible that more recent planes (787, 350) which use composite materials behave differently in that respect, but I don’t know the properties of the composite materials involved, and I don’t know if the main structure of the plane uses them.

In terms of regulations, I’m pretty sure this isn’t allowed by many or most countries and/or airlines.

Comment: Most Sat phones operate in the L-band: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L_band#:~:text=Iridium%20Communications%20satellite%20phones%20use,between%201525%20and%201646.5%20MHz. - wavelength is between 15cm and 30cm (and both Iridium and Inmarsat are right in the middle). So wavelength would indeed be a concern.

Answer (score 5):

Of course not.

Radio transmitters/receivers are specifically forbidden UNLESS a specific device on the exception list (mainly phones & tablets). I can't count the number of times I've heard "everything with a transmit or receive function must be turned off"

The airline is likely to enforce this, since they want to make money out of you using their WIFI instead.

For United, for example, see: https://www.united.com/ual/en/us/fly/travel/inflight/devices.html

Comment: Thanks, do you have any idea regarding the technical feasibility?

Comment: Antenna placement is crucial here. If you have a window seat with line of sight to the nearest satellite,  you may get ok connectivity. The rest going to be hit or miss and also depend a lot on fuselage material: aluminum vs composite.

Comment: @Hilmar it also depends if you are using a geostationary or low earth orbit based sat phone system.  But I doubt in a plane you could deploy an antenna suitable for a geostationary based system (or even see the satellite), and I doubt from a single passenger window seat you would get decent  handover for a LEO based system

Comment: My GPS receivers have always worked when against the window, and sometimes worked in my lap or seatback pocket when I had a window seat.  I never tried the Iridium, since it also transmits.